# app fabric local cache tracing with ETW

Tags: appfabric, etw

We have a problem that after some time at production, the client of the app fabric caching work very slow. since we work with local cache we thought that something wrong there. After i examined the entries at the trace of the **app fabric client**, i saw an entry that contains "Count = 450000" the number is very high and increases every day exponential. The settings of the local cache:  objectCount="500000" ttl="300".

1) How can i know how many items exist at the local cache. Does the "Count =x" at the trace entry means that the local cache has x items?

2) What can be the reason that the number of items at the local cache increase and gets to 500000, while the itemCount at the server is about 4000?

thanks